# Add ScrollPane into FlowPane

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I want to insert ScrollPane into FlowPane:

```
public FlowPane infrastructurePane()
    {

        final FlowPane flow = new FlowPane();
        flow.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        flow.setVgap(5);
        flow.setHgap(5);
        flow.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        final ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane();

        scroll.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);    // Horizontal scroll bar
        scroll.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);    // Vertical scroll bar
        scroll.setContent(flow);
        scroll.viewportBoundsProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Bounds>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Bounds> ov, Bounds oldBounds, Bounds bounds)
            {
                flow.setPrefWidth(bounds.getWidth());
            }
        });

        //flow.setPrefWrapLength(170); // preferred width allows for two columns
        flow.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");

        for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++)
        {
            flow.getChildren().add(generateRectangle());
        }

        String cssURL = "/com/dx57dc/css/ButtonsDemo.css";
        String css = this.getClass().getResource(cssURL).toExternalForm();
        flow.getStylesheets().add(css);

        return flow;

    }

    public Rectangle generateRectangle()
    {

        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(10, 10, 10, 10);
        rect2.setId("app");
        rect2.setArcHeight(8);
        rect2.setArcWidth(8);
        //rect2.setX(10);
        //rect2.setY(160);
        rect2.setStrokeWidth(1);
        rect2.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
        rect2.setWidth(220);
        rect2.setHeight(180);

        return rect2;
    }
```

But when I run the code I cannot see the `ScrollPane`. Can you tell me what am I missing into my code in order to make the `FlowPane` scrollable?

EDIT

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accroding to the code, you want "Add FlowPane into ScrollPane" right? The scrollpane cannot be seen because it is defined in infrastructurePane() method locally but not added to the scene. Return scrollpane in that method. Also you need to set the prefHeight of the flowpane when the view port is changed. Also you may want to use stackpane as a top container. Here the full demo:

```
public class FlowInScroll extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().addAll(infrastructurePane());
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public ScrollPane infrastructurePane() {

        final FlowPane flow = new FlowPane();
        flow.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        flow.setVgap(5);
        flow.setHgap(5);
        flow.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        final ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane();

        scroll.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);    // Horizontal scroll bar
        scroll.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);    // Vertical scroll bar
        scroll.setContent(flow);
        scroll.viewportBoundsProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Bounds>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Bounds> ov, Bounds oldBounds, Bounds bounds) {
                flow.setPrefWidth(bounds.getWidth());
                flow.setPrefHeight(bounds.getHeight());
            }
        });

        //flow.setPrefWrapLength(170); // preferred width allows for two columns
        flow.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");

        for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
            flow.getChildren().add(generateRectangle());
        }

        String cssURL = "/com/dx57dc/css/ButtonsDemo.css";
        String css = this.getClass().getResource(cssURL).toExternalForm();
        flow.getStylesheets().add(css);

        return scroll;
    }

    public Rectangle generateRectangle() {

        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(10, 10, 10, 10);
        rect2.setId("app");
        rect2.setArcHeight(8);
        rect2.setArcWidth(8);
        //rect2.setX(10);
        //rect2.setY(160);
        rect2.setStrokeWidth(1);
        rect2.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
        rect2.setWidth(220);
        rect2.setHeight(180);

        return rect2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I manage to fill the stage with the ScrollPane by this code: `Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();

        scroll.setPrefSize(primaryScreenBounds.getWidth(), primaryScreenBounds.getHeight());` But is this the best way?

Comment: @PeterPenzov. Try scroll.setFitToWidth(true) and scroll.setFitToHeight(true). Also try to put scroll into StackPane instead of VBox.

Comment: I tried to add scroll.setFitToWidth(true);
        scroll.setFitToHeight(true); but it's not working. With above code only I get the desired result.

Comment: @PeterPenzov. As I said put the scrollpane into stackpane instead of Vbox. Also post the code where the infrastructurePane() is called.